# How do I make a VS build fail when 1 or more NUnit tests fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0

I just started to play with this guy. Is there any way to include it on my Build plan? Or Visual Studio's Build? So that when some test fails the project will not build? I've seen some people asked it but the answer is not that clear for me. A step-by-step would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: not sure what you mean by "build plan". would you please elaborate? Are you using a build tool at all or do you just mean you want building inside visual studio to not build if the nunit tests fail?

Comment: Yes the second one, building it inside visual studio :)

Comment: The code you are testing will have to be built before the tests are able to run. Within VS I would expect your tests to fail and get highlighted to the dev in question. In a CI / CD pipeline using something like VSTS you could setup a build to fail when the tests fail and prevent it going to the next step in the pipeline